# Override query in sql string possible? C#

Tags: c#, sql, overriding

Currently I'm working with my local MSSQL database and when I make a connection all works good. However that is not the question I'm having right now; I want to make my code cleaner and I don't want to have duplicated code or almost duplicated code.

For now I'm working with one large class that holds all the methods to selecting, creating, updating and/or deleting an user. But I think it can be writen down better with an override string that rides over the sql string inside the code.

Only thing is that I'm (for now) a complete noob and have no idea how to accomplish this... please help? As an example I've set the two regions, might change them to classes, below.

```
        #region Select Data from Database
        public DataTable Select()
        {
            // static method to connect to database
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstring);
            // to hold the data from database
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                // sql query to get date from database
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users";
                // for executing command
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                // getting data from database
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                // database connection open 
                conn.Open();
                // fill data in datatable
                adapter.Fill(dt); 
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // throw message if any error accures
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
            }
            finally
            {
                // closing connection 
                conn.Close();
            }
            // return value in datatable
            return dt; 
        }
        #endregion


#region Search User on Database using KeyWords
        public DataTable Search(string keywords)
        {
            // static method to connect to database
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstring);
            // to hold the data from database
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                // sql query to get date from database
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE id LIKE '%"+keywords+"%' OR first_name LIKE '%"+keywords+"%' OR last_name LIKE '%"+keywords+"%' OR username LIKE '%"+keywords+"%'";
                // for executing command
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                // getting data from database
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                // database connection open 
                conn.Open();
                // fill data in datatable
                adapter.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // throw message if any error accures
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // closing connection 
                conn.Close();
            }
            // return value in datatable
            return dt;
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: Just use the Search() method and switch the query string if keywords is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Read https://xkcd.com/327/ and whatever solution you go with fix `id LIKE '%"+keywords+"%'`

I encourage you to research an object mapper, like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) which will make your methods return types (e.g. User)  and not raw `DataTable`s. An ORM can help pushing you into the pit of success.

As for reuse you can notice that your methods that do SELECT look very similar so you could make a helper method DataTable ExecuteSelect(string sql) which you could reuse from your `Search` and `Select` methods.

You really must fix this `'%"+keywords+"%'` issue. SQL injection is no joke.

Comment: I would second on Dapper suggestion :) Although I can't use it for several reasons out of my control, I loved it.

Answer (score 0):

Think about changing your entire concept and work with entity framework.

That way you create a connection to the DB and class for each main entity you have there.

Afterwards all your selects, updates, deletes etc will be automatic with all the functionality you have in MSSQL.

Comment: I'd use Dapper over EF!

Answer (score 0):

(This would be a mess as a comment)

First of all you must write code that is trustable and doesn't have unnecessary additions. ie:

```
   #region Select Data from Database
    public DataTable Select(string sql)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            // getting data from database
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, myconnstring);
            // fill data in datatable
            adapter.Fill(dt); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // throw message if any error accures
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        }
        // return value in datatable
        return dt; 
    }
    #endregion


    #region Search User on Database using KeyWords
    public DataTable Search(string keywords)
    {
        // to hold the data from database
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String sql = @"SELECT * 
                          FROM tbl_users 
                          WHERE id LIKE @pattern OR 
                                first_name LIKE @pattern OR 
                                last_name LIKE @pattern OR 
                                username LIKE @pattern";
        try
        {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstring))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pattern", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = '%"+keywords+"%';
            // database connection open 
            conn.Open();
            // fill data in datatable
            tbl.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // throw message if any error accures
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        // return value in datatable
        return dt;
    }
    #endregion
```

First spare time to understand why you should use parameters, how you would use then etc.
Next, you would quickly see that this pattern is not flexible and not worth to make into a class as is.

You should think about getting away from DataTable and DataSet as well. Look into Linq and Entity Framework (Linq To EF). Others already found the wheel for you. Read about different patterns like Repository pattern. And also read about different backends and their advantagaes\disadvantages, weighing it against your use cases, before coding specifically for one of them.